# Why is [n] easy to be velarized efter a back rounded vowel?

Tags: phonetics, phonemes

So [n] becomes similar to [ŋ], as in "on" and "-ion". What is the phonetic phenomenon and in what languages becomes /ŋ/ separated diachronically from /n/ affected by the vowels?

Comment: There may be a language which shows this phenomenon, but I can't think of one off the top or my head.

Comment: This would be a form of (progressive) assimilation between the final consonant and its preceding vowel. I wrote an [answer on Chinese SE](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/dissimilation-of-bilabial-finals-following-middle-chinese-%E6%B3%95-%E5%93%81-%E5%87%A1/2558#2558) about consonant-vowel _dissimilation_.

Answer (score 2):

Some dialects of German (notably Ripuarian (Kölsch) and Moselfränkisch) show this phenomenon. Here words like *Balkon* are pronounced /balkoŋ/ and also *schön* becomes /ʃɛŋ/. I don't know what diachronic process is underlying this development, but I suspect an influence from French: A French nasal vowel is replaced with vowel+ŋ in German.

And here's a map on *Balkon* and *Karton* from [Atlas Alltagssprache](http://atlas-alltagssprache.de/r10-f9ab/)

Comment: If schön becomes /ʃɛŋ/, that doesn't sound like what the OP is asking about, since /ɛ/ is neither back nor rounded.

Comment: It is not clear what happened first: The transition /n/ to /ŋ/ or the unrounding of the ö.

Comment: And the transition to /ŋ/ itself may be the final outcome of a nasalization (as suggested by the French connection). As an analogy, In northern (West) Lombard dialects, /ŋ/ is found in words like *stazion*, while in the more southern dialect of Milan that's a nasalized /u:/ instead, so this alternation isn't unheard of; the northern dialects are conceivably more influenced by either German or French, too. And as to the shift from /o/ to /ɛ/, I think the common understanding in French is that all the nasalized vowels shifted *due* (and thus, after) the nasalization happened, not before.

Comment: @jknappen But /œ/ is also not a back vowel. Or are you saying the shift to /ŋ/ happened before the umlaut? Or is roundedness a reason to velarize the following nasal?